# How to get Parameter value and insert it into query SAP ABAP

Tags: parameters, abap

I have one problem, i make Report with Parameters, and than i have to take value from one parameter and isert it into Select query, but my Value is always null, wenn i make default value befor report start all functionert.

when i tried this all is okay

```
PARAMETERS p_name TYPE char30.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR p_name.

p_name = 'ARNOLD'.

SELECT * FROM zyy_pat_final_db INTO TABLE tb_pt WHERE NAME = p_name.

CALL FUNCTION 'F4IF_INT_TABLE_VALUE_REQUEST'
    EXPORTING
*     DDIC_STRUCTURE  = ' '
      retfield        = 'name'
*     PVALKEY         = ' '
      dynpprog        = sy-repid
      dynpnr          = sy-dynnr
      dynprofield     = 'p_name'
*     STEPL           = 0
*     WINDOW_TITLE    =
*     VALUE           = ' '
      value_org       = 'S'
*     MULTIPLE_CHOICE = ' '
*     DISPLAY         = ' '
*     CALLBACK_PROGRAM       = ' '
*     CALLBACK_FORM   = ' '
*     CALLBACK_METHOD =
*     MARK_TAB        =
* IMPORTING
*     USER_RESET      =
    TABLES
      value_tab       = tb_pt
*     FIELD_TAB       =
*     RETURN_TAB      =
*     DYNPFLD_MAPPING =
* EXCEPTIONS
*      parameter_error = 1
*      no_values_found = 2
*      OTHERS          = 3.
*  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
* Implement suitable error handling here.
*  ENDIF.
```

I do not know, why do I get no results without my input, what I've written in code

```
PARAMETERS p_name TYPE char30.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR p_name.

********p_name = 'ARNOLD'.

SELECT * FROM zyy_pat_final_db INTO TABLE tb_pt WHERE NAME = p_name.
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapat_selection-screen_events.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_7@7@) is clear enough: "`The events for the field help and input help do not transport data between the selection screen and the ABAP program. As with general dynpros, suitable function modules such as RS_SELECTIONSCREEN_READ...`"

Answer (score 0):

Actually the requirement is not that clear first: and if the selection parameter needs the value for select query then the function module used will not help... try with this code given

```
 BEGIN OF ty_mat,
    sign(1)   TYPE c,
    option(2) TYPE c,
    XXXXX(low)    TYPE ANY,
    YYYYY(high)   TYPE ANY,
  END OF ty_mat.

  DATA:  it_mat             TYPE TABLE OF      ty_mat,
         wa_mat             TYPE               ty_mat.

  LOOP AT it_TABLE INTO wa_TABLE.          "added
  wa_sam1-sign = 'I'.
  wa_sam1-option  = 'EQ' .
  wa_sam1-low = "aNY VALUE".
  APPEND wa_MAT TO it_mat.
  ENDLOOP.


and now pass it_mat to your select query with IN parameter...
```